# VBA code won't act properly through "button" but when you try step by step through F8 it works perfect

Tags: excel, vba

I've created macro which was working perfect in any ways. But then I needed to unprotect and then at the end of action protect it. So I added 2 sub (protect and unprotect) then I called it from main subs. When you go through it step by step (F8) it again works perfect. But when you try to click on button it act in another way (like giving message in another sheet and etc.)

Lets try fix **Sub DeleteLastInformationInReyestr()**

```
Option Explicit

Public MainID As String
Public ReyestrID As String
Public RN As Long
Public Cell As Range
Public bIsEmpty As Boolean
----------------------------------------

        Sub CopyPasteFirstRow()
            
    Call Unprotect
    
            MainID = Sheets("Main").Range("CS7").Value
            ReyestrID = Sheets("Reyestr").Cells(Rows.Count, 97).End(xlUp).Value
            bIsEmpty = False
            
       If MainID = ReyestrID Then
       
           MsgBox "This content has been already added!", vbCritical
             
       Else
            For Each Cell In Sheets("Main").Range("E7:F7,H7:R7,T7,AA7")
                If IsEmpty(Cell) = True Then
                    bIsEmpty = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Cell
                
                If bIsEmpty = True Then
                    MsgBox "Please enter all nessecery info", vbCritical
                Else
                      
             Sheets("Main").Range("E7", Range("E7", "DL7")).Copy
             Sheets("Reyestr").Activate
             Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
             Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End If
        End If
        
    Call Protect
        
    End Sub
    
    Sub DeleteLastInformationInReyestr()
        
    Call Unprotect
    
        MainID = Sheets("Main").Range("CS7").Value
        ReyestrID = Sheets("Reyestr").Cells(Rows.Count, 97).End(xlUp).Value
        RN = Worksheets("Reyestr").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If MainID = ReyestrID Then
                
                 Worksheets("Reyestr").Activate
                 Worksheets("Reyestr").Range("E" & RN, Range("E" & RN, "DL" & RN)).Clear
    
        Else
                 MsgBox "You can clear only last added content!", vbCritical
            
        End If
    
    Call Protect
    
    End Sub
    
    
    Sub DeleteInsertedInfoFromMain()
        
    Call Unprotect
    
        Dim Answer As Integer
        Dim WsReyestr As Worksheet
        Dim WsMain As Worksheet
        
            MainID = Sheets("Main").Range("CS7").Value
        Set WsReyestr = Worksheets("Reyestr")
        Set WsMain = Worksheets("Main")
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WsReyestr.Range("CS:CS"), WsMain.Range("CS7")) > 0 Then
            Sheets("Main").Range("E7:Z7,AD7:AV7,BD7:BE7,BH7:BJ7,BO7:CM7,CQ7").ClearContents
        Else
            Answer = MsgBox("Yuxarida qeyd olunan melumat reyestre elave olunbayib! Melumati reyestre daxil etmeden silmek isteyirsiz?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Diqqetli olun!")
                If Answer = vbYes Then
                    Sheets("Main").Range("E7:Z7,AD7:AV7,BD7:BE7,BH7:BJ7,BO7:CM7,CQ7").ClearContents
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End If
    
    Call Protect
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub Protect()
                   
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Protect "PassABC", userinterfaceonly:=True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reyestr").Protect "PassABC", userinterfaceonly:=True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reyestr").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        
    End Sub
    
    Sub Unprotect()
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Unprotect "PassABC"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reyestr").Unprotect "PassABC"
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: You may be getting clashes as `Protect` and `Unprotect` are functions in VBA. Try renaming your subs from those and try again (Something like `ProtectSheets` etc). Are you actually getting an error or whats actually occurring when you run it properly?

Comment: Thx for answer @Simon. I renamed it to `ProtectIT` and `UnprotecIT`. It acts the same way as before.

>Are you actually getting an error or whats actually occurring when you run it properly?

Comment: `Sheets("Main").Range("E7", Range("E7", "DL7")).Copy` (for example) will fail if Main is not the active sheet, because Range with no sheet qualifier always defaults to the active sheet (in a regular code module)

Comment: ^^-- in other words, using an unqualified range within a qualified range does not assume both ranges are from the same sheet.

Comment: @Simon 
>Are you actually getting an error or whats actually occurring when you run it properly?    
-- When i try fullfill Sub DeleteLastInformationInReyestr by button It works like it should (say the second part when msgBox appears) but it goes to sheets("main") and selects DM1:DM7 while when you go step by step it stays at page "reyestr" as it should.

Comment: Well you do need to fix what Tim said above. Also maybe try specifying the sheet when you paste as well. So instead of `Cells(Rows.Count, 5)...` you do `Sheets("Reyestr").Cells(Rows.Count, 5)...` Maybe see if that works.

Comment: @TimWilliams Understood. Will try activate each sheet before referring to Range

Comment: I would suggest instead of activating the sheet you just qualify all your Range() and Cells() calls with a worksheet object.  It's good practice to not have your code rely on any specific sheet being active.

Comment: @TimWilliams @Simon @braX thx a lot guys. I appreciate your advices. Made this changes and it works perfect:
                `Else`  <br/>  
                 `Sheets("Reyestr").Activate  'this was added`
                 `MsgBox "You can clear only last added content!", vbCritical`

Comment: @TimWilliams before activating sheet I did exactly like you suggest but that won't work in this situation. Will examine this issue later.